# Spivak's Inverse Function Thoerem

Tags: calculus

I've gone through numerous posts about Spivak's proof of the inverse function theorem in Calculus on Manifolds. But I can't find any that address this part.

Inverse Function Theorem
Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuously differentiable in an open set containing $a$ and det $f'(a) \neq 0$. Then there is an open set $V$ containing $a$ and open set $W$ containing $f(a)$ such that $f: V \rightarrow W$ has a continuous inverse $f^{-1}:W \rightarrow V$ which is differentiable and for all $y \in W$ satisfies $(f^{-1})'(y) = [f'(f^{-1}(y))]^{-1}$

He states the following:

There is a closed rectangle $U$  containing $a$ in its interior such that $f(x) \neq f(a)$ if $x \in U$ and $x \neq a$.

Since $f$ is continuously differentiable in an open set containing $a$, we can also assume that

1. $det f'(x) \neq 0 $ for $x \in U$

and

2. $|D_jf^i(x) - D_jf^i(a)| < 1/2n^2$ for all $i,j$ and $x \in U$

Where did these two facts come from?

Comment: How can anyone answer if you don't tell us what $U$ and $n$ are?

Comment: “1” is simply the same as saying _without loss of generality_ we can assume that $U$ is contained in the open set containing $a$ within which $f$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: Could you clarify on the second (the notation)? What’s $D_j$—$j$th derivative?; and $f^j$—$j$th component of $f$?

Comment: $D_j$ denotes derivative with respect to $j$th argument; $f^j$ is indeed the $j$th component of $f$.

Comment: The $j$th partial derivative of the $i$th component of $f$

Comment: @JackLeGrüß   Sorry, could you elaborate on why assume that U is contained in the open set containing a within which f is continuously differentiable implies $det f'(x) \neq 0$

Comment: You mention that he states that there exists $U$ with $a\in int(U)$ (and I’m quite sure he’s already **demonstrated** injectivity of $f$ in $U$); then he mentions the existence an open set $\mathcal{O}\ni a$ such that $f\in C^1(\mathcal{O})$. Because he further states that we can **also** assume $\det f’$ to be nonvanishing in this $U$, he’s only replacing $U$ with a smaller one, inside $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: I think it comes from the fact that $f'$ is continuous, so therefore $det f'$ is continuous (since det is just a polynomial of all the entries of the matrix), and therefore $|det f'(x) - det f'(a)|$ can be made arbitrary small if $x$ is close enough to $a$, thus $det f'(x) \neq 0$ since it was assumed that $det f'(a) \neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

Here are the sequence of steps Spivak makes:

- The first paragraph explains why there is no loss of generality in assuming that $Df_a=\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^n}$.
- Next, by definition of $Df_a$, and our previous assumption that $Df_a=\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^n}$, we must have $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\lVert f(a+h)-f(a)- h\rVert}{\lVert h\rVert}=0$. Because of this, there exists an open set $U_1$ containing $a$ such that for all $x\in U_1$, $f(x)\neq f(a)$.
- Since $f$ is by assumption continuously differentiable, and because determinant is a continuous function (actually, it is even a polynomial in the matrix entries, so this is very nice), the composition $\det \circ f':\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous. Since $(\det \circ f')(a) = \det[f'(a)]\neq 0$ by assumption, continuity implies that there is an open set $U_2$ such that for all $x\in U_2$, we have $(\det\circ f')(x)\neq 0$ (in fact we can choose the $U_2$ such that the sign is the same as $\det f'(a)$).
- Since $f$ is continuously differentiable, all the partial derivatives $D_jf^i$ are continuous. Thus, by the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition (with $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2n^2}$, which is a positive number), we can find open sets $V_{ij}$ (for example you can take them to be open balls centered at $a$ with sufficiently small radius) such that for all $x\in V_{ij}$, we have $\left|D_jf^i(x)- D_jf^i(a)\right|< \frac{1}{2n^2}$.

Now, let $V= U_1 \cap U_2 \cap \bigcap_{i,j}V_{ij}$. This is the intersection of finitely many open sets which contain $a$, hence $V$ is open and contains $a$. Because it is open, we can further find a small enough closed rectangle $U$ such that $a\in \text{int}(U)\subset U \subset V$.

Basically, the idea is that you find an open set small enough for all the purposes. Now, with this $U$, it is clear that

1. for every $x\in U$, $f(x)\neq f(a)$.
2. for every $x\in U$, $\det f'(x)\neq 0$
3. for every $x\in U$, and every $i,j$, $\left|D_jf^i(x)- D_jf^i(a)\right|< \frac{1}{2n^2}$.